# Is it possible to check if a type "matches" a generic type in Python?

Tags: python, python-typing

Not sure how to phrase the question correctly, so I'll give an example. Suppose I have the following code:

```py
import typing as T

A = T.List[T.Any]
B = T.List[float]
```

Now I want to be able to check whether the type `B` "matches" (for lack of a better word) or "is a subtype" of the type `A`. I.e. would a value of type `B` be valid if it was returned from a method with the return type hint of `A`.

Using `==` works only if two types match literally (i.e. `List[Any] == List[Any]` is `True`, whereas `List[Any] == List[float]` is `False`). Since `Any` could represent any type, I'd like to be able to have a function `is_matching(a, b)` such that `is_matching(List[float], List[Any])` would return `True`. Is there any built-in way to achieve this in Python?

Answer (score 0):

So there currently doesn't exist a way to do this natively in python, however I think this should be possible with a combination of `get_args` and `get_origin`. The below function works for all the things I've tested it with:

```py
import typing as T

def is_subtype(sub_t: T.Any, t: T.Any) -> bool:
    if t == T.Any or sub_t == T.Any:
        return True
    try:
        return issubclass(T.cast(type, sub_t), T.cast(type, t))
    except:
        pass
    if T.get_origin(sub_t) == T.get_origin(t):
        args_sub_t = T.get_args(sub_t)
        args_t = T.get_args(t)
        return all([is_subtype(arg_sub_t, args_t[i]) for i, arg_sub_t in enumerate(args_sub_t)])
    else:
        return False

class C:
    pass

class D(C):
    pass

A = T.List[T.Any]
B = T.List[float]

print(is_subtype(A,B))
print(is_subtype(B,A))

A = dict[C, D]
B = dict[D, D]

print(is_subtype(A,B))
print(is_subtype(B,A))
```